# nodejs pcap tcp segment

Tags: node.js, tcp, pcap

My Node.js program use for capture packet from specific port and analyse the data from binary stream.

Normally the range of packet length should be 100 - 300 but sometime with some reason the destination server got hang and didn't send data to my program. And later on when it back, it sent a bulk of binary data. Which is separate to many TCP stream packets as a picture in this link.
[Picture to show the packets detail](https://dl-web.dropbox.com/get/Screenshots/Screenshot%202015-04-29%2015.06.24.png?_subject_uid=6931335&w=AAC97vaMWrIi5Uyc_fBE2MYNPZbtlSkjOj86ODAXYLQhqg)

I capture those packets and open with Wireshark. I realise that those packets doesn't came with PSH flag in TCP layer except the last one. And with incorrect sequence, my program can't work properly as expectation (it crash).

Can somebody tell me how to handle with this situation ? Do I need to consider the PSH flag and reassembly those packets before process the logic by node.js program.

Reference:
https://github.com/mranney/node_pcap